# Swift Animate duration not working in CGAffineTransform

Tags: swift, animation, cgaffinetransform

When I am translating one view with an animation of 1 second it is not working, but when I am executing the transform.identity it works fine.

Here is my code:

```
func hideCarousel() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.carouselER.transform  = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 200)
    })
}

func showCarousel() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.carouselER.transform = .identity
    })
}
```

[image: Carousel Not Working]

Comment: Did you try adding `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` at the end of your animation blocks?

Comment: Yes, I tried but the problem wasn’t that the view was not layouted, the problem was that it wasn’t doing animated, it was problem that it was getting executed in a different queue because I had more view controllers, I have posted my answer below :)

Comment: @PabloSanchezGomez I have created a new project and check your code. It works normally without DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: @trungduc I am having lunch, I will try to give you a example project or more information for this questions and do more testing with your other answer!  thank you

Answer (score 4):

To solve this issue I forced the animation to run in the main thread. Every time that you have problems with the performance of your UI elements like your animations or updating your label texts, try forcing to run the UI change in the main thread.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.carouselER.transform  = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 200)
        })
    }
```

I have also faced that problem with one timer that updated a label, but in this issue I thought it was some kind of problem of the CGAffineTransform.

[image: Carousel Working]