# Unexpected layout behaviors without DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, user-interface, grand-central-dispatch

Sometimes when the autolayout or the UI changes are not getting performed as I want I wrap the code into a `DispatchQueue.main.async` and it gets solved (e.g):

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

But debugging this code with (`Thread.current`) without the `DispatchQueue` it tells me that is already in the main thread but it doesn’t do the animation well, and just adding the `DispatchQueue.main.async` works fine. I would like to know what does exactly `DispatchQueue.main.async` to make that it works. Because I thought it just made that the code gets executed in the main thread, but if it is already executing in main thread it shouldn’t do anything… But with this it works fine and without is creating layout issues.

(It has happened to me with different pieces of code and different apps, and I have always debugged and tells me that is already in the Main thread).

I thought it could be because a bit delay generated by dispatchQueue, but it has happened to me in more places where a delay is not needed ([Swift Animate duration not working in CGAffineTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547386/swift-animate-duration-not-working-in-cgaffinetransform/50547387#50547387) -> Today I have debugged this issue without the dispatchMainQueue and it is getting executed in main thread as well but it is not working without the dispatch)

Comment: You're testing on real devices, right? You shouldn't test threading on a Simulator. Also, without seeing what context you're calling `tableView.reloadData` from it's hard to tell if that code should indeed be already running on the main thread or not.

Comment: Simply, when you use DispatchQueue.main.async, self.tableview.reloadData() will be called after a small delay (because block will be executed in the next loop). That's why you have difference.

Comment: I have updated my question, to check if the code is already running in the main thread I was printing Thread.current and it was telling me that I was in the Mainthread and checking with breakpoints as well.

Comment: @trungduc It has happened to me in scenarios where the delay doesn't affect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547386/swift-animate-duration-not-working-in-cgaffinetransform/50547387#50547387 (In this post I have debugged as well that the animation was getting executed in Main Thread without adding the DispatchQueue.main)

Comment: @DávidPásztor Yes, I am testing it in real devices (also, I have replied you before without mentioning you)

Comment: Funny I have noticed the exact opposite with the newer devices that wrapping code in a dispatch main when already on the main thread I get weird results like it is executed first even though I know in theory it should be after everything else in the function executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply, when you use `DispatchQueue.main.async`, `self.tableview.reloadData()` will be called after a small delay (because block will be executed in the next loop). That's why you have difference.

In this case, `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` is executed when device *will* be rotated. It means that something maybe wrong at this time and device hasn't rotated yet. So if you call `self.tableview.reloadData()`, it will may give a wrong result.

*Why `DispatchQueue.main.async` resolves the problem?* - It's because `DispatchQueue.main.async` give a delay before block is executed and with this delay, `self.tableview.reloadData()` will be called after device is finish rotating . That's why it gives right result

Do it with `animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)` and you won't need to use `DispatchQueue.main.async`

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
  coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: { (_) in
    self.tableview.beginUpdates()
    self.tableview.endUpdates()
  })
}
```

Comment: I am going to try and let you know, (but, It has happened to me in scenarios where the delay doesn't affect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50547386/swift-animate-duration-not-working-in-cgaffinetransform/50547387#50547387 (In this post I have debugged as well that the animation was getting executed in Main Thread without adding the DispatchQueue.main)

Comment: I have tried this solution and it keeps making an unexpected layout behavior :(

Comment: My answer focus in current question. With your other question, you should provide enough information where method is called. I tried the code in your question and it works normally without using DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: Could you explain about this unexpected layout behavior?

Comment: I have stack views inside the tableviewCells and they are not resizing fine. You were right about the delay! (It keeps me giving fail calling it in the traitCollectionDidChange because it is not getting called when the device rotates) (I am doing it on iPad), What is working is to place it in the coordinator.animate(alonsideTransition, completion), if you want edit your answer and I set it as correct :)

Comment: Ah you are right. It's because the trait collection are all Regular for vertical and horizontal on both iPad portrait and landscape. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Done! (Also if instead adding tableview.reload data, you use beginUpdates and endUpdates, it makes the animation more smoothly)